# Using CSS "content" property breaks form interaction

Tags: html, css, forms, interaction

As a usability feature I'd like to add highlights to the currently focused form element, in a similar fashion to [the moneysupermarket forms](http://www.uxforthemasses.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/moneysupermarket-form-example.png). I'm working with an HTML pattern for building forms that I *cannot* change:

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="name">
    Name
  </label>
  <input id="name" type="text" value="Fred">
</div>
```

I thought I'd come up with a simple solution: I'll add `focus` and `blur` events to all inputs, selects and textareas that toggles a `.hasfocus` class on the wrapping div, then hook styling on that class.

Here's a **[demo on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kufiwe/2/edit?html,css,output)** but if you're using Firefox or Chrome 40 you may see the issue I have: Adding the CSS `content` property to the `div.field` **breaks the form interaction**, it seems the initial mouse click is swallowed by the browser & you're unable to select the content. I'm stumped, I think it may be a browser bug. Any ideas how I can make the highlighted elements behave as the others?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Here's a screencast that demonstrates the issue: http://screencast.com/t/LlmwcsZ2qYM

Comment: OK. By the way, your two text inputs don't seem to have any anomalous behaviour. Only the select does behave as you say (not dropping down on the first click).

Comment: @MrLister Try highlighting the text inputs content with one mouse down. You can on the first two controls but not the ones with the highlight. I've managed to whittle it down to the use of the `content` property it seems!?

Comment: If you switch your events to `mouseover` & `mouseout` it works. So basically a `select` doesn't listen to a `focus` event.

Comment: @TimVermaelen good idea but that's not quite the behaviour I'm after, e.g. keyboard users tabbing between fields won't get the highlight & moving the mouse away will loose the highlight even when there's still focus in the field.

Comment: @raggsyboy Oops, I'm sorry, I see I missed an update. So now I am on Gecko v35, and the inputs do behave as you said. So yes, that _was_ something that changed between v34 and v35. I'll go and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable reproduce in Chrome 42, but I did reproduce this in Firefox 37. It appears as though adding the highlighting to the label element fixes the issue:

```
.field.hasfocus label:before {
    content:"";
    ...
}
```

Updated JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/kajifoquci/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You missed your test-x references.
The whole idea with the focus on the field through the labels, is the mapping of the `for` attribute with the `id` attribute. The `name` attribute alone is not going to cut it. Since `id` has to have a unique value on the page, I ended up at 5.

```
<label for="test5">
    Test 5
</label>
<!-- name="test4" -->
<select id="test5">
  <option value="">one</option>
  <option value="">two</option>
  <option value="">three</option>
</select>
```

So you can simplify your logic with:

```
$('input, select, textarea').on('focus blur', function (){
    var el = $(this),
        field = el.closest('.field');

    field.toggleClass('hasfocus');
});
```

You can keep the `.control.hasfocus:before` to disable this effect on `.control` classes.

Hope this helps.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/pz8v1w1n/)**

Comment: thank you for your answer but I think you maybe misunderstood what the issue is? Using Firefox or Chrome 40 you're unable to select the contents of the text inputs or choose a select on the initial mouse down click. This seems to be associated with using the content property.

Comment: I'm not sure if this help but I made a simple screencast to try demonstrate the issue. http://screencast.com/t/LlmwcsZ2qYM

Comment: No it doesn't help. Because that's what I've solved with my solution. Also I see you clicking on the fields themselves. How about clicking on the labels? Hence the `for` & `id` mapping is very important.
So change the mapping, copy/paste my js and test with click on the fields, labels and using tab. They all worked for me in FF.

Comment: I think we're talking at cross-purposes. Although you've provided a cleaner looking JS function, that's not where my issue is. In the screencast I show how the initial mouse click in the input creates the required highlight (via the classname toggling) but I'm unable to select the text contents (during the same initial click), neither am I able to make a selection from the `select`. Following clicks perform as expected.

Comment: The selection issue doesn't seem to be a problem of mine (FF, Chrome 40, IE9, IE10, IE11). Can you test on [this link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/tive/pz8v1w1n/show/) pls? For browser support <IE9, you need to use jQuery v1.x.

Comment: I still see the issue, I'm on OS X Yosemite & Mavericks maybe it's a platform issue? Here's a screencast with the mouseclicks visible http://screencast.com/t/IsL8zO3cm I still have to click on the text inputs twice to be able to select the content. The initial click is still swallowed by FF (35.0.1) or Chrome 40.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but do you see what I mean now? This doesn't address my issue.

Comment: Yes ic now, and you're right that the css `content` seems to be the cause of this issue. You're most likely better off without the `:before, :after` and re-slice your `table` structure. Every browser does it's own little usability features regarding focus, double click, triple click, text selection and blur events. For that reason I wouldn't try to script the position of the cursor and the text selection.